# Laravel return encrypted id, the id will be overrided with 0

Tags: encryption, response, laravel-6

What I am trying to achieve is that I want to return the encrypted id, but the function will change it to 0 instead of the encrypted value. I made a helper function for encrypting the id, pass by reference.

```
if (! function_exists('encryptID')) {
    /**
     * Generate the URL to a controller action.
     *
     * @param $data
     * @param array $keys
     */
    function encryptID(&$data = [], $keys = [])
    {
        // if(empty($keys)) $keys = ['id'];
        foreach($data as &$aData) {
            foreach ($keys as $aKey){
                if(isset($aData[$aKey])){
                    $aData[$aKey] = encrypt($aData[$aKey]);
                    $aData['_' . $aKey] = encrypt($aData[$aKey]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the controller

```
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $tasks = $this->user->tasks()->get();

        encryptID($tasks, ['id']);

        return response()->apiSuccess($tasks);
    }
```

apiSuccess function:

```
        Response::macro('apiSuccess', function ($responseData) {
            return Response::json([
                'success' => true,
                'body' => $responseData
            ]);
        });
```

The result the api returns:

```
[
        {
            "id": 0,
            "title": "aaa",
            "description": "bbbbbb",
            "created_at": "2019-11-16 04:13:21",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-16 04:13:21",
            "_id": "eyJpdiI6InFweGtISm1jaE9vOFRuZDBuSUt5WVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiOUQzSE1nWTc4MXM2UnRZQ3BScXNCQT09IiwibWFjIjoiNzM1YWU0Y2UwZjdkN2ZmNDM5MmYzYTRhNTI0YTI4ZDdjNTU5N2M1M2E4NWQyZGRiMzI4MzVjNGFiMjUxMmU4NiJ9"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "title": "aaa",
            "description": "bbbbbb",
            "created_at": "2019-11-16 04:14:53",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-16 04:14:53",
            "_id": "eyJpdiI6ImtBeU92cWhuT05FS3NSYXErOCtKWUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMTRMN2tTV3Q3SGFzVWE0Q2ZOUXJlQT09IiwibWFjIjoiNzZjMThkMzViMDg4ODllNzk3ZTc3MWMzN2FiYzhmZTg2ZGI2MmM2Y2IzOWM5ZGQ4NTJiMDMwMTZjOTBjN2ZlMiJ9"
        }
]
```

If I change the key = ['title'], it works as expected.

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "eyJpdiI6Ikc5bjNWc0pmd2Y2b1lvTFo3M25sVlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoieEpLRFwvTVUwckZkbjVCVGwrZ3pMMUE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjA2NTJhYzNjMjBiMzliYmMyYTYxMjU4N2VmOGFhZTVmMGUzZjBhNzdlMTFjYTQ2YTFkNDA0ODVmMTljZmIzZTMifQ==",
            "description": "bbbbbb",
            "created_at": "2019-11-16 04:13:21",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-16 04:13:21",
            "_title": "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"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "eyJpdiI6IkVIbVBGcWhCanA1UzBPRnZ1S2RXY1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiN2JSWG1nV1B1Z0lFWEJHOVBPaDh5dz09IiwibWFjIjoiYWQwMzA0NmRhZDc4MzEwNTRhZTFhZWI2MThjYzAzZTg2ZWEzOTAyNzhmNTkwNDU3ZTA0ZWIzYjdhOTM3NWFlNSJ9",
            "description": "bbbbbb",
            "created_at": "2019-11-16 04:14:53",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-16 04:14:53",
            "_title": "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"
        }
]
```

As you can see all ids will be changed to 0, instead of the encrypted value. I am confused, why would that happen. I made a new key "_id" to test if the encryption is successful, it turns out that the encryption works, but somehow reassign the value to id does not work.

Laravel version: 6.2,
PHP version: 7.2.

Anyone knows the reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` field is set as the primary key and 'incrementing'. When you get this attribute it will be cast to an integer because it is 'incrementing' and set as integer by default.

You can set `$incrementing = false;` on the model to stop this particular cast.

```
0 === (int) "some string"
```

Comment: If I set the $incrementing = false, do I need to specify the id when inserting a new row into mysql database?

Comment: no, your table in the database is set to have the auto increment field ... this variable is just telling the model to expect the primary key to be incrementing

Comment: yup, it stops the casting to integer